# Can't find WSO2CarbonDB in wso2is-5.7.0 debian package installation

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have installed wso2is-5.7.0 from the debian package.  My datasources has WSO2_Carbon_DB using jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB which is defined in the tomcat/Catalina-server.xml.  When I run wso2server.sh start it fails with the log lines:

TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-17 12:33:25,611] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.inter
nal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in looking up data source: Name [WSO2CarbonDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [WSO2CarbonDB].

I do not reference WSO2CarbonDB anywhere in my configuration.  Below is my user-mgt.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>wso2admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>admin</UserName>
                <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>
        <AuthorizationManagerclass="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
        <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>                       
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://ldap.xyz.com:389</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=ldapadmin,ou=People,dc=xyz,dc=com</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPassword">secret</Property>
        <Property name="passwordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
        <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=People,dc=xyz,dc=com</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=account)</Property>
        <Property
        name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=account)(|(uid=?)(mail=?)))</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Group,dc=xyz,dc=com</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=posixGroup)</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">ou=Groupshare,dc=xyz,dc=com</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=posixGroup)</Property>
        <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(objectClass=organizationalUnit)</Property>
        <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
        <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">memberUid</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
        <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
        <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
        <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
    </UserStoreManager>
</Realm>
</UserManager>
```

How do I get rid of the [WSO2CarbonDB] reference or appease it?  I have tried adding a datasource for it and a jndi definition for it with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using LDAPUserStoreManager, the JDBC data source defined under Realm configuration (in user-mgt.xml) is still required to store the permission information. Please refer [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+the+Authorization+Manager) for more info.

> According to the default configuration in WSO2 products, the Users,
>   Roles and Permissions are stored in the same repository (i.e., the
>   default, embedded H2 database). However, you can change this
>   configuration in such a way that the Users and Roles are stored in one
>   repository (User Store) and the Permissions are stored in a separate
>   repository.
>
> A user store can be a typical RDBMS, an LDAP or an external Active
>   Directory.
>
> The repository that stores Permissions should always be an RDBMS. The
>   Authorization Manager configuration in the user-mgt.xml file (stored
>   in the /repository/conf/ directory) connects the system
>   to this RDBMS.

As you have defined following entry in the `user-mgt.xml`,

```
  <UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
                <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
```

You have to define the corresponding data source info in `master-datasource.xml` file (stored in the /repository/conf/datasources direcotory)

Eg:

```
    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>carbon db</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
           <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/carbondb</url>
           <username>dbuser</username>
           <password>password</password>
           <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

> How do I get rid of the [WSO2CarbonDB] reference or appease it? I have
>   tried adding a datasource for it and a jndi definition for it with no
>   luck.

Make sure JNDI name defined in `master-datasources.xml` exactly matches with the `dataSource` name configured in `user-mgt.xml`.